# Looking for a specific Sci-Fi Book series with female lead

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a scifi series I read a few years ago.
I think there are 3 books. Could be more.
The protagonist is a woman who was sold by her father and grew up as a sex-slave to some pirate leader (not a erotic scifi book).
She gets rescued by the military in the beginning of the first book (she kills the pirate leader) and is able to give the the routes the pirates use from memory. She has some kind of superhuman capabilities in navigation.

After that she joins the military.
It is not Sassinak by Anne McCaffrey although pretty similar.

Comment: Not the _Gap_-series by Donaldson? First book is _[The Real Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Real_Story)_ as per [this ID request](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/52108/19561).

Comment: Don't have enugh reputation to comment.
But no. It was' t the Gap-series. The story starts when she is just 12 years old or something like that and describes how she ended up as a slave and then jumps to when she was freed. Also she is a sex-slave at the beginning of the story there are no erotic scenes included. After the proloue/intro she isn't a slave anymore. It just her "origin story".

Comment: You can [edit] you're own question however and answer the comment there. That would be a good way to do it. Also clearly mark the edit in your question and say that you added additional information in response to SQBs comment.

Comment: Also, it looks like you've created two accounts. You can find the details of how to merge accounts at http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. You can always edit and add comments to your own posts, plus you can see that the two accounts have different icons and different reputation scores.

Comment: This reminds me a little of Daughter of Time - http://www.amazon.com/Daughter-Time-Trilogy-Erec-Stebbins/dp/1942360037/

Comment: @McMe Now that you've identified the book in question, please add this as an answer so that we can mark the question as solved. Also, you might like to take FuzzyBoots's advice on [merging your accounts](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts); it would then be much easier for you to keep track of your own questions, e.g. editing them without needing the edits to be approved by other users.

Comment: @McMe There's also a nifty badge you get for answering your own question.

Answer (score 4):

Since OP doesn't seem to be coming back, I shall do the honours.

This is [The Alecto Initiative (Loralynn Kennakris #1)](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17934930-the-alecto-initiative) by Owen R. O'Neill.

> Life's never easy out in the Methuselah Cluster, the most remote
>   region humanity ever settled, but when her alcoholic father found her
>   a 'job' while he went off-planet to look for work for a 'few months',
>   11-year-old Loralynn Kennakris began to learn just how ugly it could
>   get. Within the year, her employers sold her to a brutal slaver
>   captain, who took from her the last thing she owned: her name.
>
> Most girls in Kris's position last a year or two. The strong ones
>   might last four. Kris survived for eight before she was set free,
>   thanks to the Nereidian League Navy.
>
> Unfortunately, eight years growing up in Hell prepared Kris for nearly
>   everything but freedom, and her new life isn't at all what she
>   imagined. Not only must she find her way in a bewildering society full
>   of bizarre rules, but the very people who rescued her think she's a
>   terrorist plant, a beautiful interstellar celebrity is complicating
>   matters in more ways than one . . . and now someone is trying to kill
>   her.
>
> But Kris hasn't stayed alive by respecting boundaries or obeying
>   rules, and her adopted society is about to find out what it's like to
>   collide with a someone who has no concept of a no-win scenario.

[image]